# Unable To Launch Chrome Browser Because Driver Is Null

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, junit4

I am executing my code using shell scripting file and as per requirement if i will not pass parameter then my code will execute on my local machine  and if i will pass parameter with shell scripting then code should be execute on browser stack. If i am executing with parameter then my code is working fine . But if i am not passing parameter in shell scripting then  unable to launch chrome browser because in If condition  driver is null. This is my base class

When i am executing shell script without parameter then my execution is going in If condition but unable to launch chrome browser because driver variable is not initialized in if condition . if i am printing driver value then it is showing null.

```
package com.epath.smoketest.tests;
/** 
 * Class: Base 
 * Author: D Albanese 
 * Creation Date: 4/5/2017 
 */

import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.rules.ExternalResource;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.LocalFileDetector;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Base {
    //-Browser capability passed by CLI argument.
    private static String sBrowser;
    //-Browser version passed by CLI argument.
    private static String sBversion;
    //-OS capability passed by CLI argument.
    private static String sOsName;
    //-OS version capability passed by CLI argument.
    private static String sOsVersion;
    //-Passing input folder name by CLI argument.       
    public String sFolderName = "resources";
    public static String getExecutionPath;
    public static String getResourcePath;
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public Base(String sBrowser, String sBversion, String sOsName, String sOsVersion,String sFolderName) {
        this.sBrowser = sBrowser;
        this.sBversion = sBversion;
        this.sOsName = sOsName;
        this.sOsVersion = sOsVersion;
        if(null != sFolderName && ! sFolderName.trim().equals("")) {
            this.sFolderName = sFolderName;
        }
    }

    //-Utilizing ExternalResource rule to preserve functionality of @Before and @After annotations in tests
    //-ExternalResource rule has before and after methods that execute prior to methods annotated with @Before and @After
    @Rule
    public ExternalResource resource = new ExternalResource() {

        @Override
        protected void before() throws Throwable {
            //-Use this for local testing

            DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
            caps.setCapability("browser", sBrowser);
            caps.setCapability("browser_version", sBversion);
            caps.setCapability("os", sOsName);
            caps.setCapability("os_version", sOsVersion);
            caps.setCapability("folder_name", sFolderName);
            caps.setCapability("browserstack.local", "true");

            if(sBrowser.length() == 0 && sBversion.length() == 0 && sOsName.length() == 0 && sOsVersion.length() == 0)
            {           
                System.out.println("Inside If Condition ");
                //-Load the properties
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                InputStream input = null;
                input = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") +
                        "/epath/services/tests/resources/AutomationData.properties");
                prop.load(input);
                //  getResourcePath=prop.getProperty("resources_path");

                getExecutionPath = prop.getProperty("local_resources_path");
                System.out.println("Print Execution Path :- " +getExecutionPath);
                System.out.println("Print Driver Path :- " + driver);
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome", "\\\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();

            } else {
                //-Load the properties
                System.out.println("Inside else Condtions ");
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                InputStream input = null;
                input = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") +
                        "/epath/services/tests/resources/AutomationData.properties");
                prop.load(input);
                getResourcePath=prop.getProperty("resources_path");
                getExecutionPath = prop.getProperty("resources_path")+sFolderName;  

                //-Get USERNAME and AUTOMATE_KEY of browser stack
                String browserStackUsername = prop.getProperty("browser_stack_username");
                String browserStackAutomateKey = prop.getProperty("browser_stack_automate_key");
                String URL = "https://" + browserStackUsername + ":" +
                        browserStackAutomateKey + "@hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub";
                driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(URL), caps);
                //-Load the URL to be tested
                driver.get(prop.getProperty("test_url"));
                //-For local file uploads 
                ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector());

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void after() {
            driver.quit();
        }
    };

    public String getAutomationInputDataPath() {
        return this.getExecutionPath;
    }

    public static String getResourcePathFromPropertiesfile() {
        return getResourcePath;
    }
}
```

And this is my test case class where i am calling base class(above class)

```
public class AddRegisterLAs extends Base {

    private Login login;
    private Navigation go;
    private LearningActivityAdd addLa;
    private ImageAdd addImage;
    private DocumentAdd addDocument;
    private VideoAdd addVideo;
    private AudioAdd addAudio;
    private LinkAdd addLink;
    private CustomAdd addCustom;
    private AiccAdd addAicc;
    private ScormAdd addScorm;
    private RegistrationCreate createRegistration;
    private Utils utils;
    private GetVersion getVersion;

    public AddRegisterLAs() {       
        super(System.getProperty("browser"),System.getProperty("browser_version"),System.getProperty("os"),System.getProperty("ov"),System.getProperty("folderName"));      
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

        login = new Login(driver);
        go = new Navigation(driver);        
        addLa = new LearningActivityAdd(driver);
        addImage = new ImageAdd(driver);
        addDocument = new DocumentAdd(driver);
        addVideo = new VideoAdd(driver);
        addAudio = new AudioAdd(driver);
        addLink = new LinkAdd(driver);
        addCustom = new CustomAdd(driver);
        addAicc = new AiccAdd(driver); 
        addScorm = new ScormAdd(driver);
        utils = new Utils();
        getVersion = new GetVersion(driver);
        createRegistration = new RegistrationCreate(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void Shallow() throws Exception {

        //utils.logAndPrint("AddRegisterLAs");
        int maxLAs = 1000;
        int maxRegs = 1000;

        //-Print to screen to create log.  Log can be copied and pasted to Word document or elsewhere as needed.
        System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\r\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\r\n");
        System.out.println("Adding and Registering Learning Activities Automation"+ "\r\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\r\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\r\n");

        //-Load the properties
        System.out.println("\n" + "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\r\n");
        System.out.println("Read in PROPERTIES file"+ "\r\n");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------"+ "\r\n");

        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;
```

Comment: Tarun Dabbs, some part of your test code is missing..!!

Comment: @jitmat Base class code is complete . Yes my test class code is more then 1200 lines .  I shared only class only for @  Before method . because we are calling data from Base class. Currently i am getting error in base class . As per execution first base class will call then after test case class will call

Comment: curly bracket is not closed for @Test annotation. i thought the code is not complete..

Comment: This class is working fine when i am executing with parameter like   smoketest.sh chrome 60 windows 10 tarun .  from putty server .  but my requirement is   if i execute only  smoketest.sh  then execution should start in my local machine .   In base class can you please see If condition  in this block i am getting null value for driver .   Sorry but i can't share complete code of my test case . This is in working condition .   currently i am facing issue in  only Base file .  This is proper complete with bracket . this is 1200 line code.Base class is a complete class  i need help in base class

Comment: Can anyone help me in this scenario ?

Comment: Remove static from public static WebDriver driver; Then try

Comment: @Deepan   I have checked and see same null value showing   Inside If Condition
Print Execution Path :- \\192.168.10.21\volume1\ngage_dev\engineering\ngage\testing\automated\tarundata2
Print Driver Path :- null

Comment: \\\\192.168.10.21 is the path is correct inside if condition? I think we should remove two \\ before ip

Comment: @Deepan :-  I have checked with two \\  but same error is coming .  If you see in code i am trying to print driver value before chrome driver setup  but i am getting null value.

Comment: Else condition is working fine  and driver value is printing in else condition .  In Else condition  i am using RemoteWebdriver   and this is working and testing is working fine with browser stack . I am facing problem in If condition and not able to launch browser on local machine

Answer (score 0):

At first kindly check that you have access to that driver path which you mentioned inside if.

Comment: Driver path is a text. I have public static WebDriver driver in top . And i am trying to access same driver inside If condition  but when i am trying to print driver value then i am getting null .    same public static WebDriver driver is using inside Else condition and this is working fine.

Comment: System.out.println("Print Driver Path :- " + driver); //Here you will get null only because there is no life inside driver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome", "\\\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
System.out.println("Print Driver Path :- " + driver);// Here you will get driver path


at first check you have proper access to \\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe

Comment: I created new file with 3 annotation and i used same variable  and chrome driver file and my browser is launched successfully and open url . In this class i write normal code and executed with right click and run as junit .   If i am executing same code with normal junit annotation then this is working .  But in above code if you see we are using some different annonation  and we are executing our code with putty server using shell scripting .   I am getting null driver  and i have tried all cominations but not able to execute this .

Comment: I have already updated code in my base class .In If condition                  System.out.println("Print Driver value:- " + driver);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: Do me a help print driver after this lines and say what it print--->
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
                driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: It printing after System.setProperty line  .but not printing text after given driver=new ChromeDriver();                                    System.out.println("Print Driver value:- " + driver);
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    System.out.println("Hello0000000000000000000");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    Now printing   Hello000000000000000000

Comment: This is a output   Print Driver value:- null
Hello0000000000000000000null      Now i have added  driver after Hello0000000000000000000    but you can see in output same null showing

Comment: Then am sure there is a problem in getting chromedriver.exe from the path mentioned.-----
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
System.out.println("Print Driver value:- " + driver); // What you getting here???

Comment: I created new class file and i have tested same path and i can access chrome driver. exe file sucessfully .     i am getting problem only in base class .    I am getting same null value for driver after printing same after      System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");           but if i am trying to print driver value after this line  driver = new ChromeDriver();  then this value is not printing  because test case failing on this line   driver = new ChromeDriver();

Comment: You are saying script not executing after line :
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
then how you are saying that issue is with the base class.

Comment: This is a code from another class and this class is working fine i am executing this class with  right click on java class and run as junit 
                                                                      static WebDriver driver;
  
 
 @ Before
 public void setUp()
 {
  System.out.println("Print driver value  " + driver);
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "\\\\192.168.10.21\\volume1\\ngage_dev\\engineering\\ngage\\testing\\automated\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
  System.out.println("Print driver value  " + driver);
 /

Comment: Now i have changed code and now i am picking chromedriver exe same as i am picking file from at the time of execution. now i am not picking chromedriver.exe from //192.168.10.21  path . now i am getting  this error      Inside If Condition
Print Execution Path :- /mnt/engineering/engineering/ngage/testing/automated/                                                                                
/mnt/engineering/engineering/ngage/testing/automated/chromedriver.exe: /mnt/engineering/engineering/ngage/testing/automated/chromedriver.exe: cannot execute binary file

Comment: Sorry, bro no idea. Try to reduce your path size. It's too long.
Check your chrome version and driver version.
From your path, i think you using 32-bit driver make sure you running machine have 32-bit or 64-bit version.

Comment: Thanks Deepan .  Yes i am using 32-bit chromedriver version and my machine is 64 bit version .      my path is  fixed  because i am fetching lot of input data file   "/mnt/engineering/engineering/ngage/testing/automated/chromedriver.exe".

Comment: Have you fixed if you have done. Share the solution with us.